# i can't take input from user properly

Tags: c, visual-studio

i used to work with scanf(); but visual studio tells me it's not safe,
when i use fgets();  it only inputs the first two input and the third one is ignored

```
void main() {

    char c=' ';
    char s[20];
    char sen[40];
    fgets(&c, sizeof(c), stdin);
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    fgets(sen, sizeof(sen), stdin);

    system("pause");

}
```

here it implements the first two and the third fgets is totally ignored
WHY??
 and what are the good practices in taking input from user in c?

Comment: You could use `scanf_s()` instead of `scanf()`, which is what Microsoft recommends.  It is different from `scanf()` — but also similar to it — so read the manual carefully.

Comment: now how do you know it inputs only first 2!? What are the symptoms? What input did you provide? How do you know what these varaibles stored?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  i declared a char variable , char array and another char array
 the and let the user input them using fgets()  so program  asks for the first two and stops  without even displaying the third printf   that i put before the third fgets.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fgets will store the null terminator along with the carriage return inside the buffer. SO you should make sure the buffer is large enough to store your data+null terminator+carriage return. If you are taking a single character like c, then it should be an array of size 3. Character+0+\n
It's also good practice to zero initialise your arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    char c[3] = {0};
    char s[20] = {0};
    char sen[40] = {0};
    fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    fgets(sen, sizeof(sen), stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

And use int main instead of void main.

If you do want to use a single character input in fgets, you can clear the input stream yourself by reading until carriage return is pulled from the stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    char c;
    char s[20] = {0};
    char sen[40] = {0};
    fgets(&c, sizeof(c), stdin);

    while(getchar() != '\n'); //read until carriage return

    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    fgets(sen, sizeof(sen), stdin);
    return 0;
}
```